# Passing number of threads to Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

According to http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ I should be able to specify the number of user / threads for my jmeter testplan in my JMeter Gui, as:

```
 ${__property(group2.threads,,defaultvalue)}
```

where defaultvalue could be 1, 2, 3 whatever...

When I attempt to do this, my test does not even start.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function is designed to read JMeter's own properties (mainly from the file jmeter.properties). In your case you are using group2.threads which, unless you put it in there, is not present as a property.

You can either create your own custom properties and reference those or pass in properties at the command line using [_P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P).

You could also just write the value for a threadgroup in the Test Plan control in the root of the test itself as a User Defined Variable.

In fact, there are lots of options. Depends on your requirements really.